# How to perform ngram to ngram association

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, associations, n-gram

can someone point me in the right direction to address the following problem?

I have a giant list of medical terms from UMLS i.e. a sample might be

```
Disease control is good
Disease control is poor
Disease control is excellent
Drug adherence
Current drug
Sodium Valproate
Antibiotic VI
Epilepsy control is good
Frequent seizures
Clinically isolated syndrome
Fractured patella
Fractured femur
```

And I have another list of phrase that do not exactly match string for string, but are similar i.e.

```
Good control of epilepsy    -->      Epilepsy control is good
Broken tibia                -->      Fractured tibia
Currently prescribed drugs  -->      Current drugs
```

I basically want to get the best match from my second list of phrases to the first list of phrases.

I am aware of ngram collocation but this seems to find the top collocated ngrams from a single corpus of text, rather than associate an ngram with another ngram.

Do I need to be looking at string matching algorithms, or more machine learning based methods?

Is anyone aware of any packages that can do this - I looked at python NLTK and couldn't find this type of functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally first look at the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) as a basic and easy approach that may work well. I would stem the words first and then run Levenshtein.

A more sophisticated approach would be to use already trained `word2vec` models (available in Spark and [NLTK](https://streamhacker.com/2014/12/29/word2vec-nltk/)), and then aggregate vectors of words that appear in each ngram to generate vectors for ngrams. Finally, you can compare the resulting vectors and find the most similar pairs. There are libraries out there that allows you to generate these aggregated vector representations for [ngrams](https://github.com/zhezhaoa/ngram2vec) and [documents](https://github.com/cemoody/Document2Vec). You can also find related articles and come up and implement your own aggregation method given your specific need.

Comment: hi TrnKh - thanks for your input. I took a look at word2vec and managed to get some nice word associations between two different corpuses. I will check out aggregating these associations.

Comment: Nice :-)  Good to know that it worked well in this context.